# How can I Sum / Group By the results of this table

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table of hours which looks like :

[image]

I want to sum the hours_spent results for this week only and group the results by the created_by person. I have this query which returns the correct data for showing only results in this week :

[image]

```
SELECT staff_id, first_name,  last_name, date_entered, `hours_spent` as total_hours FROM hours LEFT JOIN staff ON hours.created_by = staff.staff_id where yearweek(`date_entered`) = yearweek(curdate());
```

But when I add the SUM(`hours_spent`) as total_hours and group by staff_id like the example below I get 0 results.

[image]

```
SELECT staff_id, date_entered, first_name, last_name, SUM(`hours_spent`) as total_hours FROM hours LEFT JOIN staff ON hours.created_by = staff.staff_id group by staff_id having yearweek(`date_entered`) = yearweek(curdate());
```

I'm assuming it's not working because the Having part of my statement doesn't return individual rows of dates so it breaks.

I feel like I am doing this the hard way. Should I be trying to run a second summing query on the results of the first query rather than combine it all into one (I was hoping for cleanliness). Or should I be using a subquery to filter out the dates that aren't this week then group the totals if so how could I accomplish this?

Comment: Try grouping by hours.created_by and commenting out your having statement.  That should make sure your join is correct, and see if the having is filtering out the results.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I was expecting with :

SELECT staff.first_name,staff.last_name, sum(`hours_spent`)
FROM hours
LEFT JOIN staff ON hours.created_by = staff.staff_id
WHERE yearweek(`date_entered`,1) = (yearweek(curdate(),1)-1)
GROUP BY created_by